# Script running pithing virtual environment is reaching for library outside of it

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am currently working on a project with the requirement of creating and activating a virtual environment within the script, so the professor doesn't have to do much when running the code. Sadly, I have an error saying that a a module cannot be imported and inside parenthesis it gives me my system's path.

I did this with the following code, and it shows me the whole installation process for all packages:

```
    from subprocess import run, Popen

    #Creation of the virtual environment
    run(["python", "-m", "venv", "venvIA"])
    Popen(["source ", "venvIA/bin/activate"],shell=True)
    run(["venvIA/bin/python", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"])
    run(["venvIA/bin/pip", "install", "-r", "./src/requirements.txt"])
```

And when running the following code, I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'umap_' from 'umap' (/Users/my_user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/umap/__init__.py)`

```
from umap import umap_ as UMAP

def umap2d3d(data, dims):
  reducer = UMAP.UMAP(n_components=dims)
  embedding = reducer.fit_transform(data)

  return embedding

umap2d3d(data, 2)
```

Does anyone know why the script is reaching out to a library outside of the virtual environment? I am working with macOS, Visual Studio Code, and Python 3.9.

Comment: each one of those calls runs in a fresh shell ... ie the virtual env is no longer activated in the subsequent calls

Comment: @JoranBeasley How can I make it run within the same shell?

Comment: `proc = Popen(...);proc.stdin.write("some command")` something like that .... this isnt usually how you do it you can use something like py2exe to create a binary that includes all your requirements ... or you could create some bash script to activate the library and install all dependencies... but you would not typically do it from inside a python script

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @JoranBeasley! I solved it by creating a new file with the rest of the code and running `run(["venvAI/bin/python", "src/ppl.py"])`... I normally wouldn't do it like that but that's what my professor asked for, just running a main.py and not messing with her computer's packages by using a venv that gets set up from the script without her having to do any extra work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+script